# Finding the number of cases of solving paint-tool-puzzle

Tags: algorithm

I was making a kind of paint-tool-puzzle game.

It's pretty easy to understand the rule if you see the short previews of the puzzle.

[Preview 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqHQk.gif)
[Preview 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XwUm.gif)

As you see, Some color blocks have colored triangles. When you click a triangle, it changes all the same color around it into the color of itself.

The goal is to unify the whole color blocks into one single color block.

I was trying to find the the number of cases of solving the puzzle algorithmically. So I replaced the puzzle in simple graph data structure and set up input format.

> line 1) Pair of Integers v and e : numbers of vertices and numbers of edges
>
> lines 2...v+1) one Character or pairs of Characters : color of vertex and if exists, a color of triangle inside.
>
> line v+2...v+e+1) Pair of Integers : indexes of two vertices to be linked each other.

for example, a graph of Preview 1 can be shown like this. (each vertex indicates from leftmost to rightmost color block.)

```
5 5
A C
B C
C D
D A
C B
0 1
1 2
1 3
2 3
3 4
```

(The result should be 1. There's only one way to solve the puzzle.)

Then I programmed the code in C#; Made a structure which can indicate each color block, Made several methods to implement combination of several blocks with same colors, changing color of the block when clicking the triangle...

But all things I can do with them is just brute-forcing all possible combinations of clicking every triangles, which will take a time of enormous when solving a bit more complicated puzzle.

I need more efficient way to solve the problem or I just want to know if there's any algorithm which can be run faster than factorial time or not.

I've tried dynamic programming to improve performance, but I don't think the problem can be broken down into smaller pieces and I don't have any clue to apply memoiaztion to the whole bunch of data.

I ask if you have any ideas to help me with the problem.

*ps. sorry if you felt inconvenient reading imperfect english. it's been a long time since i've posted a piece of writing in english.*